# coordinating angular2 components using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

I have the following code:
*index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart JS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfill -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/common/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
<script src='app/hero-detail.require.js'></script>
<script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/main.js'></script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

*app.component.js*

```
(function (app) {
  app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `<h1>My Heroes</h1>
      <ul class="heroes">
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
          (click)="onSelect(hero)"
          [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
          <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span>{{hero.name}}
        </li>
        <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
      </ul>`,
    styles:[`
      .selected {
        background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
        color: white;
      }
      .heroes {
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 15em;
      }
      .heroes li {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin: .5em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        height: 1.6em;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .heroes li.selected:hover {
        background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
        color: white;
      }
      .heroes li:hover {
        color: #607D8B;
        background-color: #DDD;
        left: .1em;
      }
      .heroes .text {
        position: relative;
        top: -3px;
      }
      .heroes .badge {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: small;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
        background-color: #607D8B;
        line-height: 1em;
        position: relative;
        left: -1px;
        top: -4px;
        height: 1.8em;
        margin-right: .8em;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
      }
    `],
    directives: [app.HeroDetailComponent]
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function(){
      this.title = "Tour of Heroes";
      this.heroes = [
        { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" },
        { "id": 12, "name": "Narco" },
        { "id": 13, "name": "Bombasto" },
        { "id": 14, "name": "Celeritas" },
        { "id": 15, "name": "Magneta" },
        { "id": 16, "name": "RubberMan" },
        { "id": 17, "name": "Dynama" },
        { "id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ" },
        { "id": 19, "name": "Magma" },
        { "id": 20, "name": "Tornado" }
      ];
      this.onSelect = function(hero){
        this.selectedHero = hero;
        console.log(hero);
      }
    }
  });
})(window.app || (window.app={}));
```

*hero-detail.component.js*

```
(function (app) {
  app.HeroDetailComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "my-hero-detail",
    template: `<div *ngIf="hero">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
      </div>
    </div>`
  }).Class({
    constructor: function () {
      this.hero = {
        id: 0,
        name: "Archy"
      };
    }
  });
})(window.app || (window.app={}));
```

I am trying to implement the tutorial given in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html using JavaScript but I cannot get it to work.

The `hero` property in the `HeroDetailComponent` with `id:0` and `name:"Archy"` shows up in the view indicating that the `directive:[app.HeroDetailComponent]` is executing correctly. The property `hero` for the `<my-hero-detail>` however, does not get updated to the value of `selectedHero`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify input in your Component.

The Typescript example has

```
   @Input() 
    hero: Hero;
```

in `HeroDetailComponent`

I believe the javascript syntax for that is:

```
  app.myComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector : 'my-component',
    template : "<div>hello {{test}}</div>",
    inputs : ["Hero"]
})
```

Comment: Adding `inputs: ["hero"]` to *app.HeroDetailComponent* solved my problem